# NHibernate - tries to update entities id to null

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using NHibernate and I have crossed a wired problem.
I have an entity, and I save it, after that I'm changing a field in the entity, and try to update it, but then I get an exception that it cannot update the id to null, I see at the NHibernate profiler that it is in face generates the SQL to update the id of the entity to null, although, when I debug, just before the update, it has value.

Here is my code:

```
// The save works.
_session.Save(entityToSave, entityToSave.Id);
_session.Flush()

entityToSave.AddedSession = new AddedSession { Date = DateTime.Now };
_session.Update(entityToSave);
_session.Flush(); // this is where i get the exception.
```

Any idea why?

Entities and mappings:

```
public class Message
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual AddedSession AddedSession {get;set;}
    public virtual IList<MessageToUser> MessagesToUser {get;set;}
}

public class MessageMapping : ClassMap<Message>
{
    Table("MESSAGES");
    Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Sequence("MSG_SEQ");
    References(x => x.AddedSession).Nullable().Column("SESSION");
    HasMany(x => x.MessagesToUser).KeyColumn("ID").Cascade().SaveUpdate().Inverse();
}

public class MessageToUser
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Message Message {get;set;}
}

public class MessageToUserMapping : ClassMap<MessageToUserMapping>
{
    Table("MESSAGES_TO_USERS");
    Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID").GeneratedBy.Sequence("MSG_USER_SEQ");
    References(x => x.Message).Not.Nullable().Column("MSG_ID");
}
```

Comment: [edit] your question to add class definition and mappings. Trouble probably lies here.

Comment: Alright, ive added them

Comment: `AddedSession` is not shown. It is not explicitly saved either in your code snippet, and there is no cascade set in `Message.AddedSession` mapping. Maybe should you include the full exception error message including any `InnerException`, and the generated SQL you witness to help other understand your issue.

Comment: its not in the addedSession, i have addedsession on every object in my project, and it works when i try it with them, just with the message its a prolem

Answer (score 0):

1. Use transactions and `scope.Commit()` instead of `session.Flush()` (this is not really related and if you already do that, just ignore)
2. There is no need to call `session.Update` for entities that are already linked to a `session`
3. You session does not know about the new `AddedSession.` You only add it to the `message` property but this does not make `session` to know about the new entity. You need to add it to the session first so it can do the mapping.

Try this:

```
using (var scope = session.OpenTransaction())
{
    var message = new Message();
    .... // some code here
    session.Save(message);

    var addedSession = new AddedSession { Date = DateTime.Now };
    session.Save(addedSession);
    message.AddedSession = addedSession;

    scope.Commit();
}
```